# How to replace the IP addresses within a PCAP file using Scapy

Tags: python, replace, ip-address, scapy

I want to replace the IP addresses in a given PCAP file with [Scapy](https://pypi.org/project/scapy/).

The PCAP file (e.g. `eth0.pcap`) contains captures by Wireshark.
My message is not code, it shows the data flow between 2 IP addresses. I want to replace the original 2 addresses with another 2 addresses.

#### Example

Given before:

```
message1: 192.168.10.10-->192.168.20.20

message2: 192.168.20.20-->192.168.10.10
```

I want to replace for all packages within the file:

- `192.168.10.10` (source of first package) with `8.8.8.8`
- and `192.168.20.20` (destination of first package) with `1.1.1.1`

So that afterwards there are:

```
message1: 172.10.10.10-->172.10.20.20

message2: 172.10.20.20-->172.10.10.10
```

How can I do this with?

Comment: What do you mean by `cap`? What is your code so far, any [example]?

Comment: emmm, cap means pcap file captures by wireshark, like eth0.pcap.  my message is not code, it shows the data flow between 2 IP address. I want to replace the orinigal 2 addresses to another 2 addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to modify packet capture output, like in [PCAP file format](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-gharris-opsawg-pcap-00.html).
This format is used by *libpcap* library to record captured packets to a file.

Scapy can read and write PCAP files, see the [Scapy docs for PCAP](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#pcap).

### Read, write, print, replace

To replace the IP addresses within this file, you have to read its packets into an object-model using the `rdpcap()` function.

Then you can print the IP addresses for each packet (with desired replacement).

Or you can also replace the IP within the object-model in memory.
Then write the complete model back using the `wrpcap()` function.

#### Example to print IP addresses

I used the example PCAP file [`dhcp.pcap`](https://github.com/arielril/pcap-mermaid-parser/raw/master/examples/dhcp.pcap) from [PCAP to Mermaid parser](https://github.com/arielril/pcap-mermaid-parser) on GitHub:

```py
from scapy.all import *

# load the PCAP file using rdpcap
packets = rdpcap('dhcp.pcap')

# Let's iterate through every packet
for packet in packets:
    source_ip = packet.getlayer(IP).src
    destination_ip = packet.getlayer(IP).dst
    print(f"{source_ip} --> {destination_ip}")

# TODO: replace in model and write to PCAP file using wrpcap
```

### See also

- IncognitJoe's tutorial on [Reading Pcap files with Scapy](https://incognitjoe.github.io/reading-pcap-with-scapy.html).
- [Getting source IP of packet using Scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773795/getting-source-ip-of-packet-using-scapy) for getting the IP fields of a packet.

---

Update:

#### How to replace in your case

Refined [talentldk's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72639554/5730279) with some simplification and debug-prints:

- no separate import needed (`all` imports all)
- no writer needed, just use `wrpcap` to write the read model
- use a replacement-dict with string's `replace` function where dict entry (a tuple) is passed to function using the [*unpack-operator* `*` as prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400739/what-does-asterisk-mean-in-python) resulting in 2 separate arguments (*key* is replaced by *value*)
- use `iter` over the dict's items to process all replacements (here 2 entries) where the next item can be drawn by `next` function

```py
from scapy.all import *

# rdpcap loads in our pcap file
packets = rdpcap('dhcp.pcap')

# define search
first_src_ip = packets[0][IP].src
first_dst_ip = packets[0][IP].dst

# define new ip address to use as replacement
ip_replacement = {f"{first_src_ip}" : '8.8.8.8', f"{first_dst_ip}" : '1.1.1.1'}
print(f"replacement: {ip_replacement}")

# Let's iterate through every packet
for i, packet in enumerate(packets):
    source_ip = packet.getlayer(IP).src
    destination_ip = packet.getlayer(IP).dst
    print(f"[{i:3}] original: {source_ip} --> {destination_ip}")

    # replace in model
    replacement = iter(ip_replacement.items())
    source_ip = source_ip.replace(*next(replacement))
    destination_ip = destination_ip.replace(*next(replacement))
    print(f"[{i:3}] replaced: {source_ip} --> {destination_ip}")


wrpcap("dhcp_replaced.pcap", packets)
```

Prints:

```
replacement: {'0.0.0.0': '8.8.8.8', '255.255.255.255': '1.1.1.1'}
[  0] original: 0.0.0.0 --> 255.255.255.255
[  0] replaced: 8.8.8.8 --> 1.1.1.1
[  1] original: 192.168.0.1 --> 192.168.0.10
[  1] replaced: 192.168.0.1 --> 192.168.0.10
[  2] original: 0.0.0.0 --> 255.255.255.255
[  2] replaced: 8.8.8.8 --> 1.1.1.1
[  3] original: 192.168.0.1 --> 192.168.0.10
[  3] replaced: 192.168.0.1 --> 192.168.0.10
```

Comment: many thanks for your help, I solved my problem with your idea. I have post my code under your answer.

Comment: @talentldk Glad it helped you find that solution yourself. Read [how to vote/accept in order to share feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and take the respective actions.

Comment: thaks for your update. your simplification sugggestion is sure mor efficient. with the print part, it's much easier to debug. I have accepted your answer but i am still not able to upvote it for i have not enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

[hc_dev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72636548/19336149) guided me towards the solution.
I tried to understand it and make it work in my issue.

Below is my code:

```py
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.utils import PcapWriter

packets = rdpcap('ftp.pcap')
new_cap = PcapWriter("ftp_new.pcap")
srcIp=packets[0][IP].src
dstIP=packets[0][IP].dst

#define new ip address I want use
ip1='8.8.8.8'
ip2='1.1.1.1'

#replace orinigal address
for p in packets:
    if(p[IP].src == srcIp):
        p[IP].src = ip1
    elif(p[IP].src == dstIP):
        p[IP].src = ip2
    if(p[IP].dst == srcIp):
        p[IP].dst = ip1
    elif(p[IP].dst == dstIP):
        p[IP].dst = ip2
    new_cap.write(p)

wrpcap("ftp_new.pcap", packets)
```

Comment: Good solution you developed yourself ️. See how this answer also clarified your question which I updated to be of use for future help-seekers. If you like to learn and improve, see my updated answer.